# SKConstraint.zRotation across +/- PI divide

Tags: sprite-kit

Is the behavior in the included image possible? (Where the anchor point of the node is on the far right side of the shape.)

[image: Image of SKConstraint limiting the rotation of a node to the left half of an arc defined by the limits -PI/2 and PI/2?]

Comment: Try constraining it between PI/2 and PI*3/2

Comment: No Dice. An SKnode's zRotation is always tracked from PI to -PI. If set to a value larger than PI (e.g. PI*5/4) it's dropped to the corresponding negative value (e.g. -PI*3/4). With a constraint of PI/2 to PI*3/2, once the node rotates past PI, it's value jumps to a negative value and the constrain snaps it to the lower PI/2 bounds.

Comment: Because the above behavior seems a reasonable application of SKConstraint, and because Apple's documentation make no mention of this limitation, I submitted a bug report (in addition to creating work around describe below.)

Comment: Correction, it looks like its the physics engine that constrains rotation values between PI and -PI.

Comment: Apple closed my bug report on this issue. 
"There are no plans to address this."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have identified a workaround.

I'm using a tuple for the constraint and handling it myself in the didApplyConstraints handler.

The format for the custom constraint assumes that the range begins at the first value and travels *counter clockwise* until the second value. It makes no allowances for constraint values above PI or below -PI. This solution also doesn't deal with total ranges greater than 2*PI.

Ranges that do not cross the +/- PI boundary are "normal" and can be handled normally.

Ranges that DO cross the +/- PI boundary are "goofy" and must be handled as a special case (if possible).

A solution to the special case seems impossible unless you are tracking angular velocity with an SKPhysicsBody (or manually). This value is required to identify which boundary the node likely "crossed" and should thus be constrained to.

```
// constraint = (CGFloat(M_PI/2), -CGFloat(M_PI/2))

override func didApplyConstraints() {

    var r = rotationSprite.zRotation

    if constraint.0 < constraint.1 { // regular constraint, easy to handle.
        rotationSprite.zRotation = min(max(r, constraint.0),constraint.1)
    }
    else // "goofy" constraint that crosses PI boundary
    {
        if r < constraint.0 && r > constraint.1 {
            if rotationSprite.physicsBody?.angularVelocity < 0 { // clockwise, crossed first value (so long as absolute angular vel is < 2PI
                rotationSprite.zRotation = constraint.0
            }
            else if rotationSprite.physicsBody?.angularVelocity > 0 // counter clockwise, crossed second value (so long as absolute angular vel is < 2PI
            {
                rotationSprite.zRotation = constraint.1
            }
            else
            {
                // If 0 velocity (or no velocity), no way to find out which boundary was crossed.
                rotationSprite.zRotation = constraint.0
                // Probably better to default to closest angle
            }
            rotationSprite.physicsBody?.angularVelocity = 0 // Alternately, multiply by a negative restitution factor.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: NOTE: This breaks with "normal" constraints near (-PI, #). If a node rotates clockwise across the PI divide, it snaps to the higher value instead of -PI. Similar situation with constraints near (#,PI) and counterClockwise rotations... (Working on a fix.)